# What options do I have for distributed systems using WPF?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, wcf, distributed

As the questions says, what are my options for WPF for distributed systems? It should still be actively being developed/maintained. The only thing I can think of is WCF. Do i have other options?

I haven't yet read about ASP.NET Web API. Can this be used as communication for distributed systems using WPF and is it recommended? If using ASP.NET Web API for WPF, do I need to know some "gotchas"?

I'll have 2 UI implementations: one as WPF and one as an ASP.NET MVC app. What would you recommend or maybe recommend other options?

Comment: ***"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"***. Wow, my question had nothing of that sort. I was asking options that I can use aside from WCF. Well, whatever.

Answer (score 2):

None. Simply as that.

WPF is a technology to make windows. It is part of the .NET framework. But windows do not do distributed systems, they present the front end.

You can use ANY .NET implemented backend technology to talk in a distribvuted .NET program, but none of them will use WPF.

I suggest you start learning enough about programming to realize that your UI frontend technology is just that - a UI frontend technology. You can use the rest of the programming environment totally independent of the UI Frontend technology you use.

Comment: That is not what the OP is asking.  He will have WPF and ASP.NET MVC for the **user interface** but he is asking **what other options besides WCF** can he use for distributed systems. _"The only thing I can think of is WCF. Do i have other options?"_ - g_b.  Also your comment _"I suggest you start learning enough about programming to realize that your UI frontend technology is just that - a UI frontend technology"_ is a bit harsh as he as already demonstrated the distinction

Comment: I suggest you understand the question before answering. I've done distributed applications using WPF  with WCF. I was asking for other options as I want to know other options - simple as that. @Micky Duncan - don't worry I don't find his answer harsh, just plain ignorant.